# Why the multiple assignment in array here happens this way?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I used this method to create a unidimensional array with an initializer,when i used this method for creating multidimensional arrays,and i assign to that multidimensional array one element like shown i do get that element to every element of array,how does this happen?

```
     Array.dim=function(dimensions,init){
     var a=[],i;
     for(i=0;i<dimensions;i++){
     a[i]=init;
       }
  return a;}   
         var p=Array.dim(20,0);
 p
(20) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

   var p=Array.dim(10,[]);

    p[0][0]=0;

   (10) [Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1)]
 0: [0]
 1: [0]
 2: [0]
 3: [0]
 4: [0]
 5: [0]
 6: [0]
 7: [0]
 8: [0]
 9: [0]
 length: 10
 __proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: Because `a[i]` always points to `init`. The array is being populated with the **same reference to the empty array**, hence **all the array elements in p points to the same array reference**, hence every item shows **the same reference**, which becomes [0]. In a nutshell, p[0][0] is the same as point[0][1] and so on, because both points to `init`.

Answer (score 0):

You hand over an array reference and every item shares the same object reference to the given array.

You could use a function which returns a new array for each call.

```js
Array.dim = function(dimensions, init) {
    var a = [],
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < dimensions; i++) {
        a[i] = typeof init === 'function' ? init() : init;
    }
    return a;
}

var p = Array.dim(20, 0),
    q = Array.dim(10, () => []);

q[0][0] = 0;

console.log(p);
console.log(q);
```

A slightly shorter approach.

```js
Array.dim = function(length, init) {
    return Array.from({ length }, typeof init === 'function' ? init : () => init);
}

var p = Array.dim(20, 0),
    q = Array.dim(10, () => []);

q[0][0] = 0;
console.log(p);
console.log(q);
```